# Using SSL Stream with Asynchronous System.Net.Sockets

Tags: sockets, ssl, asynchronous, stream, certificate

My server is now running using Asynchronous System.Net.Sockets but i want to use SSL stream with it. i am pretty new to using SSL so here is my server code if someone can help me with it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

    public class Wrapper
    {
        public byte[] buffer;
        public Socket _socket;
        public object connector;
    }

    public class WinSocket
    {
        private Dictionary<string, byte> Connections;
        public event Action<Wrapper> AnnounceNewConnection;//Event Handlers
        public event Action<Wrapper> AnnounceDisconnection;
        public event Action<byte[], Wrapper> AnnounceReceive;
        private Socket _socket;
        public int MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS = 2;//Max User Connections

        public WinSocket(ushort port)
        {
            try
            {
                Connections = new Dictionary<string, byte>();
                _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                _socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
                _socket.Listen(500);
                _socket.BeginAccept(AcceptConnections, new Wrapper());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);//write an exception
            }
        }

        private void AcceptConnections(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                Wrapper wr = result.AsyncState as Wrapper;
                wr._socket = _socket.EndAccept(result);
                #region Invisible
                string IP = wr._socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0].ToString();//Get user ip
                if (!Connections.ContainsKey(IP))
                    Connections.Add(IP, 1);
                else
                    if (Connections[IP] <= MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS)//Maximum Connections Per IP
                    {
                        byte connections = Connections[IP];
                        Connections.Remove(IP);//Limit exceeded
                        Connections.Add(IP, (byte)(connections + 1));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wr._socket.Disconnect(false);
                        _socket.BeginAccept(AcceptConnections, new Wrapper());
                        return;
                    }
                #endregion
                wr.buffer = new byte[65535];
                wr._socket.BeginReceive(wr.buffer, 0, 65535, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveData, wr);
                AnnounceNewConnection.Invoke(wr);
                _socket.BeginAccept(AcceptConnections, new Wrapper());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);//write an exception
            }
        }

        private void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult result)//Receiving Data
        {
            try
            {
                Wrapper wr = result.AsyncState as Wrapper;
                string IP = wr._socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0].ToString();//Get UIP
                if (Connections.ContainsKey(IP))
                {
                    SocketError error = SocketError.Disconnecting;
                    int size = wr._socket.EndReceive(result, out error);
                    if (error == SocketError.Success && size != 0)
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(wr.buffer, 0, buffer, 0, size);
                        AnnounceReceive.Invoke(buffer, wr);//The delegate
                        if (wr._socket.Connected)//Make sure socket is connected
                            wr._socket.BeginReceive(wr.buffer, 0, 65535, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveData, wr);//Start Receiving Data
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (wr._socket.Connected)
                        {
                            wr._socket.Disconnect(true);//Disconnect the client
                        }
                        byte connections = Connections[IP];
                        Connections.Remove(IP);
                        Connections.Add(IP, (byte)(connections - 1));
                        try
                        {
                            AnnounceDisconnection.Invoke(wr);
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);//write an exception
            }
        }
    }
```

So my question again clearly is : How to use SSL Stream with socket class like the ABOVE code

Comment: What error(s) are you getting? Have you tried anything else in addition to what you have included in the question?

Comment: i don't get error my code above is working but i want to use SSL in it to secure my connection and i don't know how

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `Stream` class with the [System.Net.SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) class. In addition to the above code, call [AuthenticateAsServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145064) and pass the server SSL certificate in the `WinSocket` constructor.

Comment: Sorry but a small request : could you highlight the parts that needs to be edited or edit the code i provided for me please ?. Because i am completely confused about SSL

Comment: Please help me i am trying to edit it but always i get Object reference is not set to the instance of an object